# Is it better to register css and js in yii controller?

Tags: javascript, php, css, yii

```
Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerCssFile(Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl.'/css/jquery.ad-gallery.css');
Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl.'/js/jquery.ad-gallery.js', CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
```

I want to load these files only for one particular view

Or any better idea to import CSS and Javascript in Yii framework for a particular view

Comment: if you want a file inside a particular view only what is the point of adding it inside the `action` or `controller` this is the totally wrong approach you **SHOULD** include them inside the view you want to load not the action or controller. untill unless you have a requirement of such kind that you have to load it via controller action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
  $uri = 'path to your action-specific css';
  Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile($uri, 'screen, projection');
}
```

and like this, if you want controller-specific files:

```
public function init()
{
  $uri = 'path to your controller-specific css';
  Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile($uri, 'screen, projection');
  return parent::init();
}
```

If you want this functionality on all controllers, create a subclass of CController, put these methods in there, and change your controllers to use the new subclass.

This will help you definitely

Comment: This is definitely not the answer you are telling the OP how to include files via controller action where as the question is **is it a better approach** which you didnt explained why is it better, which is definitely **NOT** untill you have no other choice or a specific requirement, you want a file overall add it in the layout, you want a file only inside a specific view load them inside the view, and your answer is a exact copy of [**`datashaman`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/4441-automagical-inclusion-of-css-file/)